# Select all MovieClips instances with code

Tags: flash, actionscript

Supose I have a MovieClip called Egg and I have a lot of Egg instances with unique names (required) or without names.

What if I need to write a code who break all these eggs refering to the Main object in Library? Instead to add code for every egg with every name in the Stage.

This is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

```
for (var index:int = Main.numChildren-1; index >= 0; index--){
    var element = Main.getChildAt(index);
    if (element is Egg) {
        element.break();
    }
}
```

'Main' is an instance that holds all your Eggs (and possibly other stuff). This iterates through everything in Main and if it's an Egg, it breaks it.

Comment: Thanks a lot wallacoloo this solve the main doubt but.

¿What if I want to change the eggs width to 400px?

?????.width = 400;

¿Where and how I put the line of code?

Thanks.

Comment: Then you'd replace 'element.break();' with 'element.width = 400;'

Comment: You´re my hero dude! Thanks a lot!